# Find adjacent CSV rows whose timestamps exceed a given duration

Tags: powershell, date, compare, timespan

I have a file with the following:

```
"BatchID","BatchName","JobName","ScannerID","DateCreated","DailyCounter"
"12713","9001","fst100","09                  ","2/6/2020 6:21:06 AM","1"
"12714","9002","fst100","09                  ","2/6/2020 6:21:42 AM","2"
"12715","9003","fst100","09                  ","2/6/2020 6:21:58 AM","3"
"12716","9004","fst100","09                  ","2/6/2020 6:22:13 AM","4"
"12717","9005","fst100","09                  ","2/6/2020 6:22:30 AM","5"
"12718","9006","fst100","09                  ","2/6/2020 6:24:54 AM","6"
"12719","9007","fst100","09                  ","2/6/2020 6:25:12 AM","7"
"12720","9008","fst100","09                  ","2/6/2020 6:55:11 AM","8"
"12721","9009","fst100","09                  ","2/6/2020 6:55:27 AM","9"
```

I want to compare date created fields and write to a file those lines that are 15 minutes or more apart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since:

- your timestamp strings are in a format that is recognized as-is when you cast them to `[datetime]` ([`System.DateTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.DateTime)) (unless your format lists the *day* rather than the month first),
- you can directly subtract two `[datetime]` instances to get a `[timespan]` instance ([`System.TimeSpan`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.TimeSpan)) whose `.TotalMinutes` property you can query

the solution is fairly straightforward:

```
$prevRow = $null
Import-Csv in.csv | ForEach-Object { # Parse the CSV rows into objects and process each
  if ($prevRow -and ([datetime] $_.DateCreated - [datetime] $prevRow.DateCreated).TotalMinutes -gt 15) {
    # Output the previous row and the current row.
    $prevRow; $_
  }
  $prevRow = $_
} # | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Encoding Utf8 out.csv
```

<sup>The above will print the matching rows to the screen; remove the `#` to export to a (different) CSV file.</sup>

Note: As written, you can end up with *duplicate* rows in the output, namely if in adjacent rows A B C both A and B and B and C are more than 15 minutes apart, in which case A B B C is output.

Documentation links:

- [`Import-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv)
- [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object)
- [`Export-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv)